# scroll view leave spaces in the bottom part

Tags: android, scrollview

Good day everyone, I put scroll view in my layout and everything work just fined but it leaves spaces in the bottom part of the content. However, I have tried `android:overScrollMode="never"` and its not working. Someone help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/login_background"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/firebase" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/companyName"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="20dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/usernameLogin"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:ems="7"
                    android:hint="@string/hintEmail"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="20dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/passwordLogin"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:ems="7"
                    android:hint="@string/hintPassword"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loginBtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="18dp"
            android:background="@color/buttonLogin"
            android:text="@string/loginBtn" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/goToGetPass"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="click"
            android:text="@string/forgetpass"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/goToRegister"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="click"
            android:text="@string/registerLine"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="20dp" />


    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOcyj.png) 
This is my screenshot. 
Please check and see where is my mistake. 
However, for another question, how do I set my layout fit every kind of screen i means the screen size of phone. Some is 4'7 inches, some 5'0 and some 6'0

Comment: Can you please elaborate your problem in detail? I am unable to see any spaces that are in the screenshot. Also update your entire xml code in the question.

Comment: @AbhishekDS u can see the bottom part of my screenshot, below the text 'register now', there are a lot of empty space which i dont want.

Comment: Got that. Update your code with the full activity

Comment: @AbhishekDS updated. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/login_background"
        tools:context=".RegisterActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/firebase"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="@string/companyName"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layout1">

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```